# Scala implicit conversion not doing on sutiable target

Tags: scala, implicit-conversion, implicit

I want `Map` to be implicit converted to `java.utils.Properties`.

```
implicit def map2Properties(map: Map[String, String]): Properties =
  map.foldLeft(new java.util.Properties) { case (p, (k, v)) => p.put(k, v); p }

val properties :Properties = Option(Map[String,String]("k"->"v")).getOrElse(Map[String, String]())

Error:(7, 82) type mismatch;
 found   : Object
 required: java.util.Properties
```

I got `Map[String,String]()` being converted first, so I got `Object` type in return.

Why not it to convert the both Map in `Option` and `orElse` together or convert the expression lazily in the end ?
How can I do to get it return Properties approprietly?

Answer (score 3):

I am not exactly sure why the scala compiler cannot find the conversion for your `Map`. But I suspect it has something to do with (maybe) erasure and the signature of `Option.getOrElse`:

```
def getOrElse[B >: A](default: => B): B
```

The result is not necessarily the same type as the original option because it could also be a super type like `Map[Any, Any]`.

There are several options how to work around this limitation:

Tell the compiler the result type of getOrElse explicitly:

```
val properties2: Properties = Option(Map[String,String](("k","v"))).getOrElse(Map.empty[String, String]): Map[String, String]
```

Use an intermediate step to tell the compiler that the option should contain Properties:

```
val propOpt: Option[Properties] = Option(Map[String,String](("k","v")))
val properties3: Properties = propOpt.getOrElse(Map.empty[String, String])

// or
val properties4: Properties = (Option(Map[String,String](("k","v"))): Option[Properties]).getOrElse(Map.empty[String, String])

// OR, shortest so far:
val properties5: Properties = Option(Map[String,String](("k","v")): Properties).getOrElse(Map.empty[String, String])
```

Answer (score 0):

Something weird is going on with implicit conversion and return type of getOrElse.
However, this works:

```
   Option(Map[String,String](("k","v"))).fold(Map[String,String]())(identity)
```

and so does this

```
   Option(Map[String,String](("k","v"))).getOrElse[Map[String,String]](Map())
```